# Date conversion and subtraction in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have my date in the below format:datetime=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`Echoing it gives me something like **20180123143852**.

Now i want the difference of two days from the date and i'm trying like this

```
dby_date=`date -d "$datetime - $date_diff " +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Error Output:

```
   date: invalid date â20180123143852 - 2 â
```

Any suggestion how to get it in the format i want

Comment: Do you want the difference between two dates, or do you want to subtract a given time from a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution :

```
datetime=20180123
date -d "$datetime - $date_diff days" +%Y-%m-%d
# -----------------------------^^^^^^
```

returns

```
2018-01-21
```

Note that I had to eliminate the time portion of your time-stamp and used `-2 days` for the subtraction.

If you need the time portion, I would recommend saving that to a separate variable then appending that value back onto your output. But as you've changed your output format, I guess the time isn't that important?

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the difference between two dates, it might be best to convert them in a format that `date` knows.

> **man date:**
>     The  `--date=STRING` is a mostly free format human readable   date string
>   such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29   16:21:42"
>   or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items   indicating
>   calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week,   relative time,
>   relative date, and numbers.  An empty string   indicates the beginning
>   of the day.  The date string format is more   complex than is easily
>   documented here but is fully described in the   info documentation.

So I would suggest to format them accordingly (`date "+%F %T"` should do the trick)

Furthermore, a difference in dates cannot be converted in a date format, so you need to do some manual work.

Lets say you have two dates in this format `$date1` and `$date2`, the difference can now be obtained as :

```
date1="2018-01-23 16:54:16"
date2="2004-02-29 16:21:42"
# Compute difference in seconds
diff=$(( $(date --utc -d "$date1" "+%s") - $(date --utc -d "$date2" "+%s") ))
# compute the separate parts (integer arithmetic)
days=$(( diff/86400 ))
hours=$(( (diff - days*86400)/3600 ))
minutes=$(( (diff - days*86400 - hours*3600)/60 ))
seconds=$(( diff - days*86400 - hours*3600 - minutes*60 ))
# print result
printf "%0.3d days %0.2d hours %0.2d min %0.2d sec\n" $days $hours $minutes $seconds

5077 days 00 hours 32 min 34 sec
```

Or you can just do

```
date1="2018-01-23 16:54:16"
date2="2004-02-29 16:21:42"
# Compute difference in seconds
diff=$(( $(date --utc -d "$date1" "+%s") - $(date --utc -d "$date2" "+%s") ))
echo $(( $diff/86400 ))":"$(date -d @$diff "+%T")
5077:00:32:34
```

Bare in mind the following here :

- The dates are converted to unix time in UTC. Not strictly needed if both dates are in the same time-zone.
- The computation does not account for leap-seconds. When a leap second occurs, unix time is reset by one and is therefor unaware of the leap second.